# Renaming vector instead of copying it

Tags: c++, stl, reference, rename, swap

I'd like to do the following. but don't know how:

```
    //have two vectors: vector1 (full of numbers), vector2 (empty)
    //with vectors, I mean STL vectors
    //outer loop
    {
    //inner loop 
    {
    //vector2 gets written more and more over iterations of inner loop
    //elements of vector1 are needed for this
    } //end of inner loop
    //now data of vector1 is not needed anymore and vector2 takes the role of
    //vector 1 in the next iteration of the outer loop

    //old approach (costly):
    //clear vector1 ,copy vector2's data to vector1, clear vector2

    //wanted: 
    //forget about vector1's data
    //somehow 'rename' vector2 as 'vector1' 
    //(e.g. call vector2's data 'vector1')
    //do something so vector2 is empty again
    //(e.g. when referring to vector2 in the next
    //iteration of outer loop it should be an empty vector in the
    //beginning.)

    } // end of outer loop
```

I was trying

```
     vector<double> &vector1 = vector2;
     vector2.clear();
```

but I think the problem is that vector1 then is a reference to vector2, which is then deleted.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You cannot use a reference to another vector, and then delete the data in the vector.  If you want to delete the data in vector2 but still keep it in vector1, you will need to make a **copy**, no two ways around it.

Comment: So I have to copy the data, although all I want is a different name for some existing data ? I know it does not work with the reference like this, but was hoping there must be another idea.

Comment: Let me ask you what is the whole point of "Renaming a vector"

Comment: @TonyTheLion: "you will need to make a copy, no two ways around it". Actually, there are three ways around it - you could move or swap the data.

Comment: Wanting to _rename_ something is a bit of a code smell: use smaller functions.

Comment: I don't see what it would help to use "smaller functions" and don't know what you mean. The vector needs to be renamed so it is recognized in the next iteration of the outer loop and at the same time I don't want to copy the vector. swap worked very well and now my program is faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you aware of this function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/swap/

```
// swap vectors
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  unsigned int i;
  vector<int> first;   // empty
  vector<int> second (5,200);  // five ints with a value of 200

  first.swap(second);

  cout << "first contains:";
  for (i=0; i<first.size(); i++) cout << " " << first[i];

  cout << "\nsecond contains:";
  for (i=0; i<second.size(); i++) cout << " " << second[i];

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The complexity of this function is guarantee to be constant.

Comment: thanks a lot. swap works perfectly fine and is easy to use and is much more efficient than than the copy instruction I was using before

Answer (score 5):

A possibility would be to use [`std::vector::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap):

```
vector<double> vector1;
vector1.swap(vector2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try swap instead.

```
std::vector<double> vector2;

{
    std::vector<double> vector1;
    // ... fill vector1
    std::swap(vector1,vector2);  
}

// use vector2 here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (and don't use a reference to the other vector if you want to keep its values):

- Overload the copy constructor (see [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/)), so that the elements of the old vector will get copied to the new vector (this is only needed if the elements of your vector are not primitive)
- Use the copy constructor

The alternative is to use the swap function.